Doesn't navigate back to app when clicking back from PDF intent
Hello I am using the below code in Compose and can't seem to figure out why when I open a PDF, then click back it takes me to the home screen and not my app. Does anyone know if there's anything I'm missing? I've looked for a few days now and can't seem to find anything helpful..
private fun openFileWithIntent(context: Context, file: File, mimeType: String) {
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${context.packageName}.fileprovider", file)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            setDataAndType(uri, mimeType)
        }
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

        try {
            context.startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
}


Perhaps that is simply how the particular PDF viewer you are testing behaves. How many PDF viewers have you tested?

Are you using the system back button or a button in the pdf viewer app itself?

I have tried with several viewers the behaviour is the same, it is the same if I click the system back button and also the button on the pdf viewer

I needed to take this line out of the manifest for the activity starting the PDF viewer
android:noHistory="true"

